# Django logging do not log with Apache

Tags: python, django, apache

My django logging works perfectly on localhost. When I pushed it to the server (with Apache), it stops working. In `tail /var/log/apache2/error.log` was reported problem with permission, so I add the permission to write in the log to www-data user. After that, file django.log was created, and Apache did not complain anymore. But the file is empty, even if I access the pages (application work).

My logging settings:

```
DJANGO_LOG_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs', 'django.log')
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console':{
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple',
            'stream': sys.stderr,
        },
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': DJANGO_LOG_PATH,
        },

    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'console'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django_crontab': {
            'handlers': ['file', 'console'],
            'level': 'INFO',
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why it does not log anything?